# Compare time and send notification in php

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have a setting table in my database where i have stored notification_time in hours

> settings :

```
notification_time
```

3

Now i have an appointment table where id(int(11)), name(varchar(50)), date(varchar(50)), start_time(varchar(50)) is saved

appointment:

```
id | name  |   date   | start_time          

1    Amit   2020-07-31   06:15:00               
2    Pawan  2020-08-01   13:30:00
```

Now i want to send notification where start_time is less than 2 hours (i.e. 2 hours before the start time) for that i have written following scripts but the issue is after time has passed it is also sending mail notification and the comparison with current time is not proper.

```
$current_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
foreach ($appointmentData as $rowAppointment) {
    $diff_in_sec = round(abs(strtotime($current_time) - strtotime($rowAppointment->date . ' ' . $rowAppointment->start_time)));

    $number_of_hours = 3600 * $settings->notification_time;
    if ($diff_in_sec >= $number_of_hours) {
        send notification;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to store date & time of the appointment in one field of type DATETIME (in MySQL). And I would use PHP's DateTime-Class [https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php] and DateInterval-Class [https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php] for calculations. Both make the solution easier.

For example:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
    // expecting that $appointment->start is already a DateTime-Object
    $diff = $now->diff($appointment->start);

    // with 'a' checking if there are zero days difference between the two datetimes, with 'h' checking 
    if ($diff->format('a') == 0 && $diff->format('h') <= $settings->notification_time) {
        // send notification...
    }
}
```